# How do you refer to an item that you already mentioned in a previous example?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, phrase-requests

This is a bit hard to explain so here's an example:

> Colors are interesting. They stimulate organisms in inexplicable ways.
>   Like, why does red infuriate bulls? Or why does blue tranquilize humans?
>   And that's not all. To us a single color can represent different emotions, sometimes contrasting ones. 
>   **[I want to announce I'm using blue as an example again]** it relates to trust and serenity, but also to coldness, sadness, and lack of emotion.

What word/phrase is the most appropriate?

Comment: Do you mean "They connote correspondingly different feelings"? Regardless, I'm still unclear about what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean, "And that's not all.  A single color can often evoke several different emotions, sometimes simultaneously." For example blue can evoke both [emotion1] and [emotion2]... Or if you want to refer to your previous example, "Blue **can also** evoke [emotion2]"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. How about now?

Comment: The first two examples talk about how colors stimulate living organisms, and the last one about the meaning we give them.

Comment: FYI                                                            Bulls are NOT infuriated by the colour red, it is movement that makes them charge.

Comment: @Joe Dark I know, I address that in the next paragraph.

Comment: Isn't this a writing advice question? You can try [Writers Stackexchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com/) also.

Comment: Simple: ***Blue*** *relates to trust and serenity, but also to coldness, sadness, and lack of emotion.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, the aforementioned colour blue can also...

Where **aforementioned** might be a good word to use.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just rephrase/recall the reference that you want to expand upon.

Why does blue tranquilize humans? And that's not all. A single color can represent different emotions, sometimes simultaneously.  [here I want to use blue as an example again]."
**Blue not only soothes us but ...**

Comment: The word is *recast* and you left out the question mark at the end of your first sentence.  (I would edit this myself but seeing as you're here)

Answer (score 1):

I would rearrange the sentences to give blue the center stage toward the end:

> Colors are interesting. They stimulate organisms in inexplicable ways.
>   A single color can represent different emotions to us, sometimes
>   contrasting ones. Red infuriates bulls. Blue tranquilizes humans [...]

Answer (score 1):

> And that's not all. To us a single color can represent different
>   emotions, sometimes contrasting ones. **If we look back at blue**, we see it relates to trust and serenity, but also to coldness, sadness, lack of emotion and vulgarity

The vulgarity I tagged on for free. See the expressions: *blue movies*/*films*; *blue jokes* and *turning the air blue*

If the OP is looking for a shorter, more concise way for referring then may I suggest *re*.

> And that's not all. To us a single color can represent different
>   emotions, sometimes contrasting ones. Re *blue*, it relates to etc.

*[re (re:), a word meaning "regarding, with reference to"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re).*

Answer (score 1):

I don't thing repeating a reference to blue is the rough spot in your formulation. It's the restatement, in different words, of an attribute of blue ( tranquility = trust and serenity) that you only just stated two sentences earlier.

Take this example:

> 1. Jim and John are doctors. They live active lives. Jim likes to golf.
> 2. Jim and John are doctors. They live active lives. Jim practices medicine and he likes to golf.
> 3. Jim and John are doctors. They live active lives. Jim, mentioned previously, practices medicine and he likes to golf.
> 4. Jim and John are doctors. They live active lives. Jim not only practices medicine, he also likes to golf.

You should see that case 1 is succinct and quite readable without distraction or loss of meaning. Mentioning Jim twice had no deleterious effect.

It's easy to see that case 2 repeats a fact about Jim twice in a short span. (I don't want to quibble about it being more specific in the second mention.)

Case 3 points to the fact that Jim was mentioned previously. It's awkward, and taking out the remark about our the previous mention gives case 1, which is readable.

Case 4 makes use of the back reference, not to the subject, Jim, but to an attribute about Jim. It is overly wordy, not succinct, making it difficult to read. (If the reader has to pause and ask why a formulation was used, then it's distracting.) Written with the phrase "not only", this back reference can be taken to emphasize Jim's ability to handle two activities at once in his life. But is it really a point worth emphasizing?

Maybe in your example, it is a point worth emphasizing. It appears to be THE point you are emphasizing, as introduced in the next-to-last sentence:

> Why does red infuriate bulls? Or why does blue tranquilize humans? And that's not all. *To us a single color can represent different emotions, sometimes contrasting ones.* Not only does blue relate to trust and serenity; it also relates to coldness, sadness, and lack of emotion.